# Catch QML error message

Tags: qt, try-catch, qml

I'm using `Qt.createQmlObject()` to create a `QML` object from a file. In the case the file is corrupted, QML outputs a message that looks like this:

`Qt.createQmlObject(): failed to create object: 
    qrc:/graphics/inline:5:2: Expected token`}'`

I'd like to catch the message in order to tell the user that his file is corrupted.

I am trying to use the third argument provided in the `Qt.createQmlObject()` but I don't understand how it works. The wiki describes the function quite well but doesn't give any example exploiting it:

https://wiki.qt.io/QML_Dynamic_Objects#Creation_of_Dynamic_QML_Objects

> The third argument is a string used as a file name in error reporting in the Qt Creator IDE. For example if an error is encountered in loaded QML string it is reported as one in the file with filename name. In invocation filename as a string has to be surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use "try-catch" block like this:

```
try {
        var newObject = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.0; Rectangle11 {color: "red"; width: 20; height: 20}',
                                       this,
                                       "dynamicSnippet1");
    } catch (error) {
        print ("Error loading QML : ")
        for (var i = 0; i < error.qmlErrors.length; i++) {
            print("lineNumber: " + error.qmlErrors[i].lineNumber)
            print("columnNumber: " + error.qmlErrors[i].columnNumber)
            print("fileName: " + error.qmlErrors[i].fileName)
            print("message: " + error.qmlErrors[i].message)
        }
    }
```

This is described in the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method)

Answer (score 1):

A more general way from Qt 5 is to install your own message handler for debug messages as described in:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler

You can then put a breakpoint in your own message handler.

This has the advantage that it works for scenarios other than Qt.createQmlObject, for example when a user action not involving your own C++ triggers the warning.