# Forcefully crash qml pages

Tags: qt, qml

My application has qml as frontend and c++ as backend.
 To check some issues, I want to forcefully made qml to crash.

Mainly I am interested what error message comes up when qml crashes on client site so that we can handle those error better.
 I have tried few things like assigning null values or null pointer on QML page but it doesnt make application crash.
 From C++ side, I load application from QQmlApplicationEngine.
Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Is quit enough? (`Qt.quit();`)

Comment: To get a better anwser please outline what your intents are and what you are trying to achieve with "crashing a QML page".

Comment: Mainly I am interested in knowing what error message it throws when it crashes

Answer (score 1):

You can use debug mode in Qt Creator.

[image]

And the application will stop when it crashes. Then, you can check your stack.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## QML won't crash :)

You can't really make some pure QML/JavaScript code "crash", at least not the same way that you can shoot yourself in the foot in C++.

Remember than QML and JavaScript are interpreted, and any error will typically generate a QML warning. Something like:

```
qrc:/main.qml:33: ReferenceError: timer is not defined
```

This error will interrupt whatever operation you're performing in your local scope, maybe mess-up a few bindings or not do exactly what you expect, but it won't "crash" your QML application.

## But you can always crash your app

If you expose some C++ component to your QML, you can technically crash your app from QML by triggering some buggy C++ code from your QML context. But this is the same thing as crashing your app from your C++ backend....

## You can catch errors (locally)

When dealing with QML/JavaScript errors, you can catch these errors the same way you would in regular JavaScript code, using `try { ... } catch(e) { ... }` mechanism, as demonstrated in [Catch QML error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049330/catch-qml-error-message)

## You can report errors (globally)

Even though not catastrophic, an error in your QML may impact the behaviour of your QML UI. One possible possible way to prevent this is to write tests for you UI where you exerce your QML components in various ways to ensure no errors ensue.

One trick we use in our test code (could work in production too), is to override the default log handler and watch out for QML errors and warnings. This allows us to test our QML components (do they behave as expected?) and also verify that no warnings were generated during these tests. The relevant documentation is available here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler

Comment: "You can't really make some pure QML/JavaScript code "crash"" Yeah, right. `Group Box { id: grp_box; grp_box.Material.border: "#112233"}` --> Qt crashes hard.